# <picture> tag is not working as it should

Tags: html, image, safari

I am trying to load different file types of the same image depending on the browser being used. To execute, I am using the  tag as follows:

```
<picture fxShow="true" fxShow.xs="false">
    <source class="image" srcset="../../../assets/Images/image.webp">
    <source class="image" srcset="../../../assets/Images/image.j2k">
    <img class="image" src="../../../assets/Images/image.png" alt="Image">     
</picture>
```

The issue is that on chrome, the webp source runs as it should, but on safari the browser attempts to load the webp and fails when it should resort to j2k or even the png. I know its not a file support issue because I've locked an img tag   with every file type as the only src and it worked fine for the browser that supports it.

Comment: Have you tried adding [the `type` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture#The_type_attribute) to the `source` elements so that the browser knows which to choose?

Comment: Is it a Safari issue then? (Don't see that tag?)

Comment: Solved. Adding the type attribute allowed the png to load on safari, so then I switched the file from j2k to jp2 and the type attribute loaded for safari.